# Extract table row data using JSoup returns nothing

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to extract table row data using **JSoup** library.But It gives  me no result as the output.

> Here is my code so far :

```
String html = "<tbody>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td><strong>Fit</strong></td>"
                + "<td>Regular</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td><strong>Color</strong></td>"
                + "<td>Multi</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td><strong>Style</strong></td>"
                + "<td>Checked</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td><strong>Fabric</strong></td>"
                + "<td>Cotton</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + "<td><strong>Model Stats</strong></td>"
                + "<td> This model has height 5'9\",Bust 32\",Waist 28\",Hip 36\"and is Wearing Size 10.</td>"
                + "</tr>"
                + "</tbody>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


        for (Element table : doc.select("tbody")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                for (Element td : tds) {
                    System.out.println(td.text());
                }
            }
        }
```

It will be grateful if any one can suggest me a way to get the out put like below :

```
<strong>Fit</strong>
Regular
<strong>Color</strong>
Multi
<strong>Style</strong>
Checked
<strong>Fabric</strong>
Cotton ... etc..
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your **`html`**. You should add **`<table>`** and **`</table>`** at the **start** and **end** of your `html` variable, otherwise Jsoup will not parse your `html` correctly, resulting in your `<tbody>` converted to `<body>`, which is why you are not able to select it in your query.

Also, to produce your desired output, use `td.html()` instead of `td.text()`.

Comment: Thank u so much. It works fine with your corrections. :)